Spring Cloud Stream Multi Cluster and Multi Input Bindings from a Single Consumer
In my project, I need to connect to two different Kafka brokers and consume all events of two topics, one topic on each Kafka broker.
My application.yaml looks somewhat like this:
spring:
    cloud:
    function:
      definition: orderCreatedListener;orderProcessedListener
    stream:
      bindings:
        orderCreatedProducer-out-0:
          destination: order-created
          binder: kafka-one
        orderCreatedListener-in-0:
          destination: order-created
          group: spot
          binder: kafka-one
        orderCreatedListener-out-0:
          destination: order-processed
          binder: kafka-two # I changed this binder between kafka-one and kafka-two manually for tests, the orderProcessedListener-in-1 binding doesn't have the exclusive producer
        orderProcessedListener-in-0: # CONSUME FROM KAFKA ONE
          destination: order-processed
          group: spot
          binder: kafka-one
        orderProcessedListener-in-1: # CONSUMER FROM KAFKA TWO
          destination: order-processed
          group: spot
          binder: kafka-two
      kafka:
        binder:
          auto-create-topics: true
          configuration:
            security:
              protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
            sasl:
              mechanism: PLAIN
        bindings:
          orderCreatedListener-in-0:
            consumer:
              enableDlq: true
              dlqName: order-created-dlq
              autoCommitOnError: true
              autoCommitOffset: true
          orderProcessedListener-in-0:
            consumer:
              enableDlq: true
              dlqName: order-processed-dlq
              autoCommitOnError: true
              autoCommitOffset: true
          orderProcessedListener-in-1:
            consumer:
              enableDlq: true
              dlqName: order-processed-dlq
              autoCommitOnError: true
              autoCommitOffset: true
      binders:
        kafka-one:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9092
                      configuration:
                        sasl:
                          jaas:
                            config: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"spot\" password=\"spot\";"
        kafka-two:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9093
                      configuration:
                        sasl:
                          jaas:
                            config: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"spot\" password=\"spot\";"


But it didn't work when I ran the application, the consumer binding from Kafka One works normally orderProcessedListener-in-0, but the other consumer binding from Kafka Two doesn't work orderProcessedListener-in-1.
I am using:

Spring Boot 3.3.0
Spring Cloud 2023.0.1

I have the two Kafka clusters running fine on my development environment with docker containers, one exposed on the 9092 port and the other exposed on the 9093 port.
Architecture example:

Kafka one with all signed consumers on all topics:

Kafka two without never signed consumers on all topics:

How do we adjust this?

My project link at the GitHub: https://github.com/jonathanmdr/Spot/tree/feature/multiple-kafka-brokers-sasl

While it is is good that you have provided a sample project, the issue is that your project contains many elements of some domain design which is specific to you and not relevant to the problem you are describing. Consider revising your sample to a very basic sample that demonstrates the issue. Also, keep in mind that multiple input/output functionality only supported by the reactive functions.

Hi @OlegZhurakousky, I created a new branch with a basic sample: https://github.com/jonathanmdr/Spot/tree/feature/poc-simple
Can you explain the reactive function more?
Do you have an example of this to share with me?

YOu can read this - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/spring-cloud-function/programming-model.html#function-arity and this https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/spring-cloud-stream/producing-and-consuming-messages.html#functions-with-multiple-input-and-output-arguments

I appreciate your help @OlegZhurakousky, the problem is that my application doesn't use reactive functions, after I applied the reactive functions the application worked by consuming multiple inputs into a unique consumer function bean.

The simple approach to solve this issue is to use two beans pointing to a unique entry point method.
Example:

@Component
public class OrderProcessedListener {

    public void consume(final Message<Order> message) {
        // your business logic to process message
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<Order>> orderProcessedFromKafkaOneListener() {
        return this::consume;
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<Order>> orderProcessedFromKafkaTwoListener() {
        return this::consume;
    }

}

The properties configuration should be:
spring:
    cloud:
    function:
      definition: orderCreatedListener;orderProcessedFromKafkaOneListener;orderProcessedFromKafkaTwoListener
    stream:
      bindings:
        orderCreatedProducer-out-0:
          destination: order-created
          binder: kafka-one
        orderCreatedListener-in-0:
          destination: order-created
          group: spot
          binder: kafka-one
        orderCreatedListener-out-0:
          destination: order-processed
          binder: kafka-two
        orderProcessedFromKafkaOneListener-in-0:
          destination: order-processed
          group: spot
          binder: kafka-one
        orderProcessedFromKafkaTwoListener-in-0:
          destination: order-processed
          group: spot
          binder: kafka-two
      kafka:
        binder:
          auto-create-topics: true
          configuration:
            security:
              protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
            sasl:
              mechanism: PLAIN
        bindings:
          orderCreatedListener-in-0:
            consumer:
              enableDlq: true
              dlqName: order-created-dlq
              autoCommitOnError: true
              autoCommitOffset: true
          orderProcessedFromKafkaOneListener-in-0:
            consumer:
              enableDlq: true
              dlqName: order-processed-dlq
              autoCommitOnError: true
              autoCommitOffset: true
          orderProcessedFromKafkaTwoListener-in-0:
            consumer:
              enableDlq: true
              dlqName: order-processed-dlq
              autoCommitOnError: true
              autoCommitOffset: true
      binders:
        kafka-one:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9092
                      configuration:
                        sasl:
                          jaas:
                            config: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"spot\" password=\"spot\";"
        kafka-two:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9093
                      configuration:
                        sasl:
                          jaas:
                            config: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"spot\" password=\"spot\";"

Anytime the best solution for this is to use the reactive functions.
